# create a direcory in pagodabox app

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a pagodabox app in codeigniter , In this app i used uploads folder to store the images, now i need to create a sub-folder named "thumb" to save thumbnail of uploaded image.
my problem is that directory is not created on server. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need Pagodabox writable storage:
https://pagodabox.com/features/shared-writable-storage

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, pagodabox uses git for source control, right? If so, why don't you just create new directory on your local repo and commit/push it? That should do the work fine. Also, pagodabox's hook file should help you set directory write permissions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Git ignores empty directories (actually ignores folders in general).
Make the directory in your local repo, and create a file in it. You can delete this file later or add it in .gitignore.

Comment: Did you execute "git add ." before commit?

Comment: yes obviously i used that command, I always used git add . command every time when pushing on pagodabox

Comment: Try "git add -f you_folder/your_file". your_file is the file you just created.

Comment: by convention if you want to persist an empty folder in your repository place an empty document called `.gitkeep` to signal your intent